# Python. Colorama. Код выводит числа вместо цвета e.g. 33m 22m 43m 44m etc

Tags: python

Я написал следующий код:

```
from colorama import *  
init() 
print(Back.YELLOW + 'hh')
```

Но он мне выводит это:

```
[43mhh
```

Почему не появляется цвет?

Comment: Нужно уточнить, как именно запускаете, какая операционная система. Если из IDLE, то это работать не будет, эмулятор терминала IDLE не поддерживает цветной текст.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так происходит потому, что Вы, скорее всего, пытаетесь записать данный текст в файл(либо же другой [file-like object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-like-object), который **не** поддерживает цветной вывод)

Если такой результат виден в терминальной сессии, то просто установите терминал, который поддерживает цветной вывод(например [konsole](https://konsole.kde.org))

Comment: Это stackoverflow на русском. Можете перевести вопрос на русский язык )